# Applying jQuery to an HtmlDivElement object in a Google Maps control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps

I'm trying to create a map legend in Google Maps v3 using jQuery UI's `buttonset()` function. I want to programmatically create the div tag, so my code looks like

```
var legend = document.createElement("div");
var input = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("id", "label");
label.setAttribute("for", "label");
label.innerHTML = "label";
input.appendChild(label);
legend.appendChild(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(legend)
$(legend).buttonset()
```

However, without the last line I get a checkbox, but when I add the last line the checkbox disappears. Is there a way for me to use jQuery UI in Google Maps? Or do I need to write it in straight Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had ordered some of the function calls incorrectly... Here is what I changed my code to.

```
var legendWrap = document.createElement("div");
var legend = document.createElement("div");
var input = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
input.setAttribute("id", "label");
label.setAttribute("for", "label");
label.innerHTML = "label";
input.appendChild(label);
legend.appendChild(input);
$(legend).buttonset() // <--- need to call buttonset() before appending 
                      //      it to the wrapped div
legendWrap.appendChild(legend) 
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT].push(legendWrap)
                      // append the wrapped div instead
```